# Topological spaces that induce "Lawvere" gauge spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

*(Warning: the following terminology is not completely standard)*

A *Lawvere metric* $d$ on a set $A$ is a function $d : A^2 \to [0\,..\infty]$ such that $d(x,x) = 0$ and $d(x,z)+d(z,y) \geq d(x,y)$. Lawvere metrics maybe ordered by $\geq$. A *pseudometric* is a Lawvere metric with $d(x,y) < \infty$ and $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$.

A *Lawvere gauge space* is a set $A$ equipped with $\geq$-filter $G$ of Lawvere metrics on $A$ (see [the nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/gauge+space)). A *gauge space* is a Lawvere gauge space only equipped with pseudometrics.

On the linked nLab page it says that a completely regular topological space $A$ defines a gauge space by letting $G$ be the set of all pseudometrics on $A$ which are continuous as maps $A\times A \to \mathbb R$.

> In this theorem: With what weaker property can I replace "completely regular" so that "pseudometric" must be replaced by Lawvere metric, i.e. how can I reasonably generalize this theorem to Lawvere gauge spaces?